# Задача состоит в том, чтобы через пробел ввести 3 значения, сумма вклада, время вклада и процент вклада

Tags: c#

Набросал такой код, внизу ошибка при отправке, моих знаний не хватает разобраться, опустим метод ввода данных, основной метод Calculate, в нем код, решающий основную задачу  принимающего строку, введенную пользователем.

```
static double Calculate(string userInput)
{
double[] parts = userInput.Split(' ');
double temp = parts[0] * (1 + (parts[1] / (100 * 12)));
double sum = Math.Pow(temp, parts[2]);
 return sum;  
}
```

Ошибка  (3,22): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'double[]'

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Прошу прощения, поправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static double Calculate(string userInput)
{
double[] parts = Array.ConvertAll(userInput.Split(' '), Double.Parse);    
double sum = parts[0] * Math.Pow(1 + ((parts[1] / 100)/12), parts[2]);
return sum;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

вы пытаетесь записать переменные типа string в массив типа double.

используйте конвертацию.

```
double[] parts = Array.ConvertAll(userInput.Split(','), Double.Parse);
```

Comment: Теперь ошибка  выглядит таким образом Error on userInput [100 12 2] expected 102.01 but was 10201

Comment: в моем примере разделение изначальной строки происходит по запятой, поменяйте на пробел

Comment: Да, я изначально пробел поставил

Comment: Ошибка осталась

Comment: код рабочий
вам нужно проверить точно ли вы все исправили согласно приведенному примеру